# Define typescript class method

Tags: javascript, typescript

I cannot find any information about "declaration and then initialization" of class method, for example can I do this (code below), first declare `getName()` and then initialize it, tslint tips me that I cannot do this, then what I should do, if doesn't want construction, like `public getName(name: string): string { return this.name }`?

```js
class Cat {
  public getName(name: string): string;
  
  constructor() { ... }
  
  getName(name) {
    return this.name;
  }
}
```

Comment: why do you want to seperate the declaration from the implementation?

Comment: I don't see any real reason to do this. Having the definition and implementation in two different places creates meaningless indirection, imo. And if it's just a linter error, there's nothing preventing you from actually doing it and disabling the tslint rule

Comment: @Thomas, I wanna make it look more like in cpp, where you in header keeps definition and in source implementation

Comment: C++ works that way so that (in theory) you don't have to recompile files that include the header if the implementation changes but the header (i.e. the interface) doesn't. That's a necessary evil of C++, it certainly isn't a good thing. There simply isn't any reason to do this in JS/TS.

Comment: TypeScript is not C++. It does not use header files.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One reason for having separate "declaration and then initialization" is that it helps to separate public interface from private implementation.

In TypeScript, one can do that by using interface as declaration and class as initialization. Also, TypeScript has module system built-in the language, so instead of having some things public and some things private in the class, you can just make the whole class to be a private implementation detail, not exported and not available outside the module:

```
export interface Cat {
    getName(name: string): string;
}


// NOTE: this whole class is an implementation detail and is not exported
class CatImpl implements Cat {

  name: string;

  constructor() { }


  getName(name: string) {
    return this.name;
  }
}

// this is exported and is publicly available for creating Cats
export function createCat(): Cat {
    return new CatImpl();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution:

```
class Cat {
    getName: () => void;
}
```